How to collect Contract Addresses via blockchain API?
Currently learning to interact with blockchain via Blockscout API to build personal database of contract addresses for future interactions. Despite trying different commands, I'm having trouble even collecting the contract addresses. Would love some guidance from anyone who's successfully navigated this.

You want to collect the contract addresses deployed by your wallet/account?

I'm interested if building my own local databases of all contract addresses on the blockchain

Dev Advocate at Chainstack here.
There are a couple of options depending on your goal.
Efficient way
If you want to efficiently build a local database of all contract addresses, a third-party API like Blockscout using the list contracts endpoint is probably the best option.
Learn how things work
If you want to build this to learn how this aspect of the blockchain works, you'll have to use raw RPC methods and iterate on each block to identify every deployed transaction.

This method is inefficient but can give you excellent insights.

Here is the main logic:
The eth_getBlockReceipts method returns the receipts of all of the transactions included in a block at once, making it an excellent way to get data on every transaction in each block.
Then, you can iterate each transaction to see if it deployed a contract. Transaction receipts have a field named contractAddress; if this field is not null, the transaction deployed a contract.
I made a tutorial about this use case and a repo.

Tutorial: Uncovering the power of eth_getBlockReceipts.

Repository for smart contract watcher.


You'll need some edits as this listens to the latest block, but you can use the logic for your indexing.
Again, keep in mind there are more efficient approaches than this, but it's an excellent way to learn how it works; also, in case you need to index data directly from the source, some institutions have that kind of requirement.

Wow, this answers everything I was trying to figure out and much more! Thank you so much!

Anytime! Glad I can help :) Feel free to reach out if you have more questions! My contacts should all be in my profile.

As per the Blockscout API docs, the API endpoint to fetch all the verified smart contracts is:
https://eth.blockscout.com/api/v2/smart-contracts
It supports pagination. So, here's the JS code to retrieve the smart contracts for the first 10 pages:
const axios = require('axios');

// Define the URL for the Blockscout API endpoint to get the list of contracts
const apiUrl = 'https://eth.blockscout.com/api/v2/smart-contracts';

// Function to fetch contract addresses for a specific page
async function getAllContractAddressesOnPage(page) {
    try {
        // Make a GET request to the API with the current page parameter
        const response = await axios.get(apiUrl, {
            params: { page }
        });

        // Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
        if (response.status === 200) {
            // Extract contracts from the response
            const contracts = response.data.items;

            // Display contract details for the current page
            console.log(`Page ${page}:`);
            contracts.forEach((contract, index) => {
                console.log(`Page ${page} - Contract ${index + 1}:`);
                console.log(contract); // Display contract details
            });

            // Return the contracts for the page
            return contracts;
        } else {
            // If request fails, throw an error with status code
            throw new Error(`API request failed with status code ${response.status}`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any errors that occur during the process
        console.error('Error fetching contract addresses:', error.message);
        return [];
    }
}

// Function to iterate through all pages and fetch contract addresses
async function getAllContractAddresses() {
    let page = 0;
    try {

        while (page < 10) // Use `while (true)` if you want to iterate all the pages
        {
            // Fetch contract addresses for the current page
            const contracts = await getAllContractAddressesOnPage(page);

            // Check if there are more pages
            if (contracts.length === 0) {
                // No more pages available, exit the loop
                break;
            }

            // Move to the next page
            page++;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error.message);
    }
}

// Call the function to fetch and display contract addresses for all pages
getAllContractAddresses();

P.S. To iterate all the pages, you can replace while (page < 10) with while (true).
